# Is there a way to clone objects and to replicate animations in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a group of spheres. I have to replicate some of the spheres of the group, so i created some clones with `.clone()` method and added them to the scene. Here i have the problem: if i change some properties of the original object (for example the color), the changes are also visible on the clone; but if i animate the original sphere, the clone doesn't animate (my animation consists in a change of the scale of the object). Does anyone have a solution? Is there a method to duplicate objects that also replicate animations?

```
// this is an example
var sphere;
var clone = sphere.clone();
scene.add(sphere);
scene.add(clone);

...

function update() {
   sphere.scale.x += 0.1;  // this does not work on the clone
}
```

I also want the clone to modify his scale, not only the sphere.

PS: I can't add `clone.scale.x += 0.1` inside the `update()` function (the code is more complex than this).

Comment: I am surprised that the clone's color property changes when you change the original, and I'm not surprised that the clone doesn't animate automatically.  The cloned object ought to be independent of the thing that it is cloned from.

Comment: Your cloned sphere uses the same material as the original one. Try doing `clone.material = sphere.material.clone();` for every clone.

Comment: I tried ```clone.material = sphere.material.clone();``` but now the color doesn't change either. Is there a method different from ```.clone()``` that can solve my problem? I'll have to change a big part of my code otherwise.

Comment: Replace the original spheres with groups that start out containing only the original spheres.  To clone, reach into the group for the original sphere, clone it, and and the clone to the group.